# Private key not working when using Google Secrets Manager in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-secret-manager

I have a Google Apps Script application that uses a service account with domain-wide delegation to make changes to user accounts on a domain. To improve the security of the application, I moved from storing the private key in code to using Google Secrets Manager with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75735362/1422413) answer. Strangely, I could see the key being returned correctly from secrets manager but it would fail to get an authorized token, throwing the following error:

```
{ [Exception: Invalid argument: key] name: 'Exception' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue after seeing [this comment](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/issues/122#issuecomment-507436277) in the GitHub repo. I just added the replacement to the retrieval function and everything resumed working correctly. I also cleared the script properties to ensure I was pulling new tokens correctly.

```
function getSecret() {
  let token, endpoint, response;
  endpoint = `https://secretmanager.googleapis.com/etc etc etc`;
  token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
      Accept: 'application/json',
    }
  });
  var decodedAPIKey = Utilities.base64Decode(JSON.parse(response.getContentText())['payload']['data']);
  var apiKey = Utilities.newBlob(decodedAPIKey).getDataAsString();
  return apiKey;
}

function getSerivce(targetEmail,scopes) {
  console.log("trying to get oauth2 service with:\n"+scopes);
  PRIVATE_KEY = getSecret().replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
  return OAuth2.createService('Gmail:' + boxEmail)
    // Set the endpoint URL.
    .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')

    // Set the private key and issuer.
    .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
    .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)

    // Set the name of the user to impersonate.
    .setSubject(targetEmail)

    // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

    // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
    // setup of domain-wide delegation.
    .setScope(scopes);
}
```